# linux + change/edit file without effecting on file date

Tags: linux, time, date, ls

I want to edit some file in my linux for example

```
ls -ltr /etc/some_file

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 188 Jul  1  2010 sysstat
```

.

```
       echo "Server101_IP=187.0.98.4" >> /etc/some_file
```

.

I expect to get the following date:

```
 ls -ltr /etc/some_file

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 188 Jul  1  2010 sysstat
```

but the date & time of this file must be not change !

I just want to edit file but I Wondering how to change the file without effect on the date & time of the file - is it possible ?

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: because I build some script that search the IP - 187.0.98.4 in all Linux directories but this script ignore if file is old then the OS creation - that the reason , so I want to test my script and see if it really ignore the old files

Answer (score 6):

You could do something with [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to get the file's Access, Modify and Change timestamps and then after editing the file you can use [touch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) to set the relevant times back to what they were originally.

Comment: @LAIN please give me exaample

Comment: @yael Tis not a "gimmeh teh c0dez" site - It is a resource for professionals who want to further their knowledge while solving a problem. Read the manual pages that Iain was good enough to link to, learn about the tools, and apply them to your situation.

Comment: simple solution that I find: touch -t 200805101024 /etc/filename